# How get the class of the div on clicking the select option inside that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs which show the product details content inside them, something like this:

```
  <div class="product-style-odd">
        <select>

            <option value="active" onClick="changeStatus(<?php echo $productid;?>,0)">Activate</option>
            <option value="inactive" onClick="changeStatus(<?php echo $productid;?>,1)">Deactivate</option>

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="product-style-even">
        <select>

            <option value="active" onClick="changeStatus(<?php echo $productid;?>,0)">Activate</option>
            <option value="inactive" onClick="changeStatus(<?php echo $productid;?>",1)>Deactivate</option>

        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
        function changeStatus(productid, status){
            //Now what I want to reference and hide that div in which changeStatus function was invoked
        }
    </script>
```

Now little explanation of above code. Both of these odd and even style divs are inside a loop so they are repeated depending upon the number of iterations in the loop. 
Now what I want to achieve is that when the user clicks on inactive option from select menu then that particular div should fadeOut and I change the status of that product via Ajax.

I don't know how to get class of that particular div which was clicked. 
And sorry for poor indentation of the code, I am not much familiar with SO editor.

EDIT:
Problem is still not solved.

The reason is the structure of that page is very complex. First I have body and then a div and then several divs and then comes a div with class product-style-even or product-style-odd. Now if I put the code to select the parent div then it selects the div after body.

Comment: an object can have multiple classes.....  which are all seperated by spaces.  So youwould need to handle that

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var selectVal;
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        selectVal = $(this).val();
    });
    if (selectVal == 'inactive') {
        var selectParentDiv = $(this).parents('div');
        selectParentDiv.fadeOut();
        console.log(selectParentDiv.attr('class'));
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjngr/3/

Comment: that pulls all the classes for the object as 1 big string. Maybe tokenize it on [space] such that there is a list of classes?

Comment: It should only return the div class of $(this).. which is the div being clicked.

Comment: since a div can have multiple classes....  it would return a string of all the classes.

Comment: I see... there isn't mention of such concern in your question. You can split the string with the space character (if need be), or check to see if your tested class exists within the returned string.

Comment: Edited to address your specifics. You can add whatever code you need within the if statement, but this should get your fadeOut() if inactive option is chosen from the select.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').click(function(){
    var divClass=$(this).parent('div').attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$(this).parents('div:first').hide();
```

in body of function changeStatus(productid, status)